# netty bootstrap uses the same workergroup but fails to use the same thread

Tags: netty

Server:

```
EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(8);
try {
     ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
     b.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024);
     b.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
       .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
```

Client:

```
    Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
    b.group(workerGroup)
        .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
    ...
    clientChannel = b.connect(host, port);
```

When server channel handler `read` a package, it makes a request to another server through `clientChannel`, 
`cleintChannel.writeAndFlush(msg->newMsg());`

However, out of my expect: clientChannel handler `read` log prints its IO thread is `ntLoopGroup-5-1`, while serverChannel handler `read` log prints its IO thread `ntLoopGroup-5-2`.

I was hoping by using netty shared eventLoop, the program could have a lower context switching rate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by use the `acceptedChannel.eventLoop()` as the group that is passed into `group(...)` of the `Bootstrap`. That is exactly what we do in our HexDump example:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/netty-4.1.25.Final/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyFrontendHandler.java#L47

Comment: when initializing bootstrap of client, there is no `ChannelHandlerContext`, unless client bootstrap is initialized in a server channelHandler.

Comment: Yeah sure as before you don't know what EventLoop the accepted Channel will be used. Alternative you can create a EventLoopGroup with size of 1 which will guarantee that the same thread is used everywhere.